# Adding a new column to a matrix conditional on the values in the other columns

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I have this dataset

```
data
     [C1]  [C2] [C3] [C4] [C5] [C6] [C7] [C8]
[1,]    5    1    2    1    4    2    1   NA
[2,]    4    1    3    4    1    1   NA    2
[3,]    3    4    6    7    1    1    2    2
[4,]    1    3   NA    1   NA    2   NA   NA
[5,]    1    NA   5   NA   NA    4    1    2
[6,]    1    4   NA   NA   NA    4    1    2
[7,]    1    4   NA   NA   NA    4    1    2
```

I want to add new column C9 which could take two values 1 (True) if the corresponding row has the value 1 in columns C2 ,C3 or C4 or 0 (False) otherwise.
I have tried this code

```
C9<-data[,2:4]==1
#change the logical matrix into numeric 
C9<-C9*1
#convert the matrix into vector #
C9<-rowSums(C9)
data=cbind(data,C9)
```

The code works well but consumes more time so  my question is there a unique way to do that , since  I am beginner in R ?.

Comment: Are you saying this code runs too slowly for you? What is the size of `data` and how long is it taking to run?

Comment: An alternative solution would be `data <- cbind(data, "C9"=apply(data[,2:4], 1, function(x) any(x==1, na.rm=T))*1) `

Comment: You say this code works for you but it does not produce what you say you want: `C9= c(2, 1, 0, NA, NA, NA, NA)`. So what do you want exactly??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, C9 must be 1 if one of C2, C3, or C4 is *exactly* 1, 0 otherwise. So the solution has to deal with `NA`s.

This compares three approaches:

```
f.1 <- function() (rowSums(data[,2:4]==1, na.rm=TRUE)>0)*1L
f.2 <- function() {x<-rep(0L,nrow(data)); x[(data[,2]==1 | data[,3]==1 | data[,4]==1)]<-1L; x}
f.3 <- function() apply(data[,2:4], 1, function(x) any(x==1, na.rm=T))*1L
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f.1(),f.2(),f.3(), times=1000)
# Unit: microseconds
#   expr    min     lq      mean  median       uq       max neval cld
#  f.1() 11.845 15.991  20.76593  18.952  22.5050   293.751  1000  a 
#  f.2() 10.660 14.806  44.43363  17.768  20.7290 25063.000  1000  a 
#  f.3() 81.137 91.797 121.80148 103.050 125.8515  2719.566  1000   b

identical(f.1(),f.2())
# [1] TRUE
identical(f.1(),f.3())
# [1] TRUE
```

`f.1()` is your approach (more or less), `f.2()` is a very simple and direct approach, and `f.3()` is from the comment. As you can see, the simple/direct approach is fastest in this case, but just by a few percent.

Why do you think this is too slow?

Comment: Super ,thanks , as I thought , there is a a unique way like the third approach , and yes my code does not work pretty well I had to add **na.rm=TRUE**

Comment: Just to be clear, the third approach is slowest. The second approach is faster than the first, but not by much. Still wondering why 18 microseconds is too slow??